# Script design many-to-many insertion with partial rollback

Tags: t-sql, rollback

I am trying to understand partial roll backs, in TSQL. Following a tutorial i  found this example but I do not understand / find can you save to a table the second object if the first fails?

```
BEGIN TRAN
PRINT 'First Transaction: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)

INSERT INTO People VALUES ('Tom')

BEGIN TRAN
PRINT 'Second Transaction: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)

INSERT INTO People VALUES ('Dick')

ROLLBACK TRAN
PRINT 'Rollback: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)
```

So if 'Tom' fails can I save 'Dick' ?
I need this, for achieving a many-to-many roll back transaction. So i create Obj A, Obj B and if both succes add Obj C, if not roll back failure, and keep the successing INSERT query.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you want to keep the first two inserts how are you rolling back?

Comment: In case if something goes wrong... I need to be able to keep the succesful aprt of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to commit the transactions as they succeed.  The code below keeps Tom, even if your script chokes on Dick...

```
CREATE TABLE #People
    ( 
        VAL VARCHAR(100)
    );

DECLARE @stop BIT = 0;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    PRINT 'First Transaction: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)

    INSERT INTO #People VALUES ('Tom')
    COMMIT 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    SET @stop = 1;
END CATCH;
SELECT * FROM #People;

IF @stop = 0
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
    PRINT 'Second Transaction: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)

    INSERT INTO #People VALUES ('Dick');
    SELECT * FROM #People;

    RAISERROR(
        'Choke on Dick' -- stop snickering
        , 16
        , 1
        );

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Rollback: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@@TRANCOUNT)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH

SELECT * FROM #People;

DROP TABLE #People;
```